# How to do things when route changes outside react-router?

Tags: javascript, react-router

I have a component outside react-router, and I want to do something when route changes. How to do this?

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {

  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    // get location and history here, but I don't know if these can help
    this.context = context;
  }

  //TODO: do something when route changes

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        my component
      </div>
    );
  }
};

MyComponent.contextTypes = {
  location: React.PropTypes.object,
  history: React.PropTypes.object
};

module.exports = MyComponent;
```

Answer (score 0):

[react-router's confirm navigation](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/latest/docs/guides/advanced/ConfirmingNavigation.md)
Maybe that's what you need,react-route's LifeCycle mixin give a method  'routerWillLeave' which will be called when the route will change